# Como eu dou echo em array

Tags: php, array

```
   public static function getAllCount(){
    $sql = "SELECT COUNT(Title) from ".self::$tablename." GROUP BY category_id";
    $query = Executor::doit($sql);
    return Model::many($query[0],new EventData());
}
 FOREACH ---

 foreach ($evcount as $c) {      
 }

 print_r($evcount);

?>  

RETORNO -----

  Array
  (
    [0] => EventData Object
    (
        [name] => 
        [lastname] => 
        [email] => 
        [category_id] => NULL
        [password] => 
        [created_at] => NOW()
        [COUNT(Title)] => 4
    )

[1] => EventData Object
    (
        [name] => 
        [lastname] => 
        [email] => 
        [category_id] => NULL
        [password] => 
        [created_at] => NOW()
        [COUNT(Title)] => 62
    )
```

Quero Dar echo puxando o `COUNT(title)=>`

Mas quando dou o echo ele da esse erro

> Call to undefined method EventData::COUNT()

Comment: De uma alias para a coluna de contagem.

Answer (score 3):

A consulta retorna um objeto com as colunas do banco que viram propriedades então trate elas de forma adequado `:COUNT()` não é um método.

```
"SELECT COUNT(Title) from ".self::$tablename." GROUP BY category_id"
```

Para resolver isso, dê um alias para coluna e depois acesse ele normalmente como um proriedade.

```
"SELECT COUNT(Title) as total from ".self::$tablename." GROUP BY category_id"
```

Dentro do foreach faça:

```
echo $c->total;
```

Se o objeto não tem métodos, é mais simples retornar um stdclass.

Comment: Retornou   o valor numero 2 e nao as [COUNT(Title)] => 62 para cada loop o  que devo fazer ? contou acredito que as categorias sem as quantidade !

Comment: @carloscoelho como vc faz essa chamada?